# im getting following exception when doing following code: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, exception, aspose-cells

```
//for loop for traversing rows
for (int i = 1 ; i < roorws.getCount() ; i++)
        {   // for loop for traversing columns
            for (int j = 1 ;j<tcols ; j++)
             {  //if column is 5
                if(j==5)

                 //printing values of cell 5 

                 System.out.print(cells.get(i,j).getValue().toString().substring(0, 26).length()+ "\t");
                 String cell1=cells.get(i,j).getValue().toString().substring(0, 26);

                 cell=cells.get("F2");
                 cell.putValue(cell1);
             }
        System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: Looks like you string is shorten than 26 charachters: substring(0, 26).

Comment: I think the lines where the printing are done. I am sure there is a string value in the cell that is not up to 26 characters of length.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the length of the string is not (at least) 26 characters. Change:

```
System.out.print(cells.get(i,j).getValue().toString().substring(0, 26).length()+ "\t");
```

to:

```
System.out.print(cells.get(i,j).getValue().toString().length()+ "\t");
```

to print the length of the string.

You can use [Apache Commons StringUtils substring() method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) to get sub string in a safe way (so it takes only at most `n` characters):

```
String cell1= StringUtils.substring(cells.get(i,j).getValue().toString(), 0, 26);
```